# Qt application assertion fails on second launch

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, assertion

Once again trying to show video in QGraphicsView. And now I have assertion failure after 2nd application launch :

`ASSERT: "m_surface" in file player\mfvideorenderercontrol.cpp, line 2346`

Here's my code:

```
pl = new QMediaPlayer();
vid = new QGraphicsVideoItem();
pl->setVideoOutput(vid);
qDebug() << pl->error();

vid->setSize( QSizeF(1920, 1080) );
vid->setPos(QPointF(-500,-500));

pl->setMedia( QUrl::fromLocalFile( path ) );
qDebug() << pl->error();

ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(vid);
ui->graphicsView->setFixedSize(1920, 1080);
qDebug() << pl->error();
pl->play();
```

I tested with *.avi and *.mp4 file. Same problem. Here's the steps:

- I am putting avi file in the path.
- Build/launch application.
- Everything is great. Video works.
- Close application, launch one more time.
- Got assertion failure.
- Change file in path to mp4.
- Build/launch application.
- Everything is fine again.
- And so on.

And if I press `Skip` in assertion window everything goes just fine again.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution. When calling set media one have a chance that not everything needed for player beeing initialized at that moment. Solution is add something like `QTimer::singleShot( 1000, this, SLOT( initAndPlayVideo() ) );` or put this slot on some button click.